# Calculate Surface Area of 2D shapes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A friend  recently had a telephone interview and he was asked a technical question:

> Q) If I wanted to calculate the surface area of some 2D shapes then what "Bucket" would I use.  He had 20 minutes to write some code and the interviewer called him back.  He sent the code via email and the code was not discussed for the remainder of the interview (there were no other technical questions).  He sent me the code:

**Windows Forms app**

```
namespace ShapesApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += form_load;
        }

        public void form_load (Object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Shape> listShape = new List<Shape>();
            Shapes.Circle circle = new Shapes.Circle();
            Shapes.Rectangle rectangle = new Shapes.Rectangle();
            Shapes.Square square = new Shapes.Square();
            Shapes.Triangle triangle = new Shapes.Triangle();
            listShape.Add(rectangle);
            listShape.Add(square);
            listShape.Add(triangle);

            foreach (Shape shape in listShape)
            {
                double a = 10;
                double b = 10;
                double surfaceArea = shape.CalculateSurfaceArea(a,b);
                Console.WriteLine("The surface area of a " + shape.GetType() + " is: " + surfaceArea);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Shapes - Class Library

```
namespace Shapes
{
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        abstract public double CalculateSurfaceArea(double Double1, double Double2);
    }

    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public override double CalculateSurfaceArea(double pi, double radius)
        {
            return (pi * radius) * (pi * radius);
        }
    }

    public class Triangle : Shape
    {
        public override double CalculateSurfaceArea(double Base, double Height)
        {
            return (Base*Height)/2;
        }
    }

    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        public override double CalculateSurfaceArea(double Length, double Width)
        {
            return Length * Width;
        }
    }

}
```

The interviewer has said that he "struggled" with the test.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Why using Windows forms if result will be printed in Console?

Comment: pi is a constant so why is it passed as a parameter and incorrectly squared?

Comment: So I can assign `pi = -15.789`? `...CalculateSurfaceArea(double pi, double radius)...`; I can have a *square* with `Length` != `Width`?

Comment: Your approach cannot be used for calculating area of trapezium. Trapezium needs three parameters

Comment: @Fabio, he was asked to produce a Windows Forms app.

Comment: What if I know *side* and *two angles* in case of triangle? Shall I consult a trigonometry and compute the `Height` myself?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, he was only asked to calculate a: Square, Rectangle and Triangle.  I added the Circle when I was experimenting with his code.  I have removed it from the question.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, the formulas he was given was: a*a for square; a*b for rectangle and (a*b)/2 for triangle.

Comment: @w0051977: `Circle` demonstrates the main, IMHO, problem of the code: it's too *rigid* and *brittle*. Whatever shape you have you should compute the area by *exactly two* parameters. So you have to pass
`PI` as a parameter, and not able to compute the area of trapezium (thanks Fabio for a good counter example)

Comment: `CalculateSurfaceArea()` shouldn't take **any parameters**.  Instead it should rely on object fields.  The parameters, if any, should be during the _construction_ of a shape. The number of parameters should vary depending on the shape.  i.e. `Circle` only needs **one**; `Rectangle` requires **two**

Answer (score 0):

Calculating area is the behavior and every shape has his own formula for calculating it. Because calculating area can involve different amount of variables and constants method will not take any parameter and variables will be concern of class which implement interface .

So I think method of calculating area can be abstracted as interface:

```
public interface ICalculatingArea
{
    double CalculateArea();
}
```

Then every shape will implement it on its own manner.

```
public class Rectangle:ICalculatingArea
{

    public double Width {get; set;}
    public double Length {get; set;}

    public double CalculateArea()
    {
        return Length * Width;
    }
}
```

In the main program it is enough to cast shape classes to the interface type and use `CalculateArea` method